# Tridion 2013 - Using dreamweaver template language

Tags: 2013, dwt

I have a question about DWT in Tridion 2013.

I have a component with field (RTF) "Description". In Tridion 2009 I wrote `@@Component.Description@@` and I got a content from this field. But when I try to use such expression in Tridion 2013 I get *Description* from Schema of current component.

Can somebody explain what was changed between versions?

I know that I can get right content from my field using this expression:

`@@Component.Fields.Description@@`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@@Component.Description@@` is a shortcut which in 2009 mapped to the only available Description field, which was your text field.

In 2013 (possibly already in 2011) they introduced a bit more content in the SDL Tridion Template Expression Language via the Dreamweaver Mediator. One of those were the description fields of a Schema. Hence that now `@@Component.Description@@` will map to the `@@Component.Schema.Description@@` field.

In my trainings I always advised against using the shortcuts, since it was up to the logic of the mediator to determine which field you would get (and even way back on R5.3 I told people that this would possibly change in the future, and it seems I was right about that). So when you need a field from a Component, you are always advised to get it via the `Component.Fields` collection.

Comment: I also did quite some work using the expression evaluator when I worked on the DGX, and can confirm that indeed it will resolve a field much faster the more qualified that field is - `Component.Fields.FieldName` will resolve faster than `Component.FieldName`. Not very different from XPath's `//fieldname` vs `/element/fieldname`

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks a lot Bart and Nuno )